# Text meniu toggle

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to change the text on a button inside a Menu every time I click on it!

Initially the text shows : **"Show point of interest"**
When i click, it is supposed to show : **"Hide point of interest"**
Again, when i click, it is supposed to show : **"Show point of interest"**

(Just like a toggle On and Off)

The button i am talking about is not actually a button, it is a userControl of a PhoneApp

Here's the code :

```
 private void makemeniu1()
           {

               Thickness th = new Thickness(); th = btnMeniu.Margin;
               LayoutRoot.Children.Add(meniu);
               meniu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
               meniu.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
               meniu.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
               meniu.Margin = new Thickness(0, th.Top+btnMeniu.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
               meniu.AddBtn("Select another Day", () => { meniu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; datePicker.ClickTemplateButton(); });
               meniu.AddBtn("Show Details", () => { meniu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; rezumattxt.Text = detailes(MainPage.dt, carlist.number); rezumatborder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; });
               meniu.AddBtn("Show points of interes", () => { meniu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; }); 

           }
```

I have this method `AddBtn` that takes a string and an Action to perform.

I have no implementing on this method such as text property to change.
It only adds text, so i can't change it!

How can a make it to toggle in the most simple way?

Thank You!

Comment: add a codeline to the buttons onClick method that changes the buttons text property and set a global boolean that indicates which string is showing for example?

Comment: Rather than creating multiple button. How about changing text on each click. That will be more easy i think. Also you can consider toggle button for the option available windows phone control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton